# Expand my mind with StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Getting answers to my questions really helps move my projects along.  It is right alongside Google with sites that I visit every day.

Sometimes, StackOverflow expands my mind.  I peruse questions looking for something to answer from time to time.  Sometimes, I'll find something where someone is trying to do something similar to what I've done, but there's a twist to it so that in the process of figuring out the answer, I learn something new.

I think it would be nice if there was some system to 'push' these kinds of questions to me.  Of course, I can use the search function, but having to come up with a search key leaves a something to be desired.

I think it would be interesting if StackOverflow could suggest questions that are likely to spark my interest based on my past history on the site and designated categories of interest.

In other words, although I'm here mostly to get answers to my questions, I think it would be grand if StackOverflow could help me find other users' questions that will expand my mind and teach me new things.

Comment: Can you search for how to construct that algorithm and report back?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980105/travelling-salesman (@Wont)

Comment: `MY MIND ===>         M        Y`            `M        I        N        D        `

Comment: @yoda: `regexprep('MY MIND','(.{1})(?!$)','$1 ')` ;)

Comment: @gnovice: ha, nice! more SO like

Comment: suprisingly, this same question was just asked yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96983/recommend-questions-to-read-answer/96986#96986

Comment: I just posted a similar question/idea here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166265/does-stackoverflow-have-capacity-to-implement-a-basic-psychohistory-engine -perhaps this deserves more attention?

Answer (score 4):

You know your history and interests better than any algorithm would.  Make the site work for you!  Have a go at the following:

- Interesting tags (heck, Tags in general)
- Subscribe to user feeds of those who are active in subjects that interest you
- Hit Reload habitually on the home page
- Click any of the links under Related on the right when viewing a question

Answer (score 1):

It sort of does this already... Questions that the site algorithmically deems might be "interesting" to you are the ones displayed on your homepage. That calculation is detailed [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

You can also help things along a bit by informing the site of your interests. Take the time to add tags to both the "favorite" and "ignore" lists in your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238260/rice-flour-cookies?tab=prefs). You can also subscribe to RSS feeds for tags that you find particularly interesting; just hover over the tag wherever you see it on the site.

Of course, there's no guarantee that the questions it finds with those tags are likely to "expand your mind" or even to "teach you new things". It's likely that if you know something well, you'll find that a lot of the questions on that subject are boring and repetitive. If you wish to take the time to answer them anyway, that would be much appreciated. But if you don't wish to do so, then you can simply ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Check the left tab of the top dropdown list on the left (says "Stackexchange" on it)

It's got lots of interesting questions (they come from all the sites on the network ~ Coincidentally the middle tab of that dropdown)

You never know what's going to be interesting till you look. But that's why they put it there. I suggest checking those out.

Often.